# Unformatted histogram values

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to find the histogram values of an image by using my own function but when i run my code it prints the histogram values like [1.000e+00 4.000e+00 1.000e+00 8.000e+00 8.000e+00 2.500e+01 2.100e+01
4.500e+01 5.500e+01 8.800e+01 1.110e+02 1.220e+02 1.280e+02 1.370e+02
Is it normal or is there any other method that i can display histogram values in an understandable way? Here is my function;

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def histogram(img):
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    hist = np.zeros((256))

    for i in np.arange(height):
        for j in np.arange(width): 
            a = img.item(i,j)
            hist[a] += 1
        
    print(hist)

img = cv2.imread('rose.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
histogram(img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you initialize your histogram, set its type to `np.uint32` or similar since you can only ever have a whole, non-negative number of pixels of a given colour:

```
hist = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.uint32)
```

Check the type of your current array and find it is `float64` with:

```
print(hist.dtype)
```

Hint: See also [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `suppress` to `True` using np.set_printoptions see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Alternatively you can print like this:

```
 with np.printoptions(suppress=True):
        print(hist)
```